# Generate large amounts sample data in S3 for Spark consumption?

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a current spark pipeline that is operating on a relatively small quantity of data. Performance testing for this quantity of data will only get me so far, and ideally I would like to test the spark pipeline on a large quantity of data.

Are there any methodologies or tools for mocking or simulating a lot of input data for spark to handle, particularly when the input comes from Amazon S3? I don't want spark to blow up when I start getting a ton more data.

I have a JSON schema that the input data must adhere to if that helps.

I don't mind if the solution involves generating the fake input data in spark itself or generating the fake input data on s3.

Answer (score 0):

Generating fake data with spark is quite easy using the `range` function.

Here is how I would go about building random data, with a predictable noisy label (but you can define any logic) in case you fancy Machine Learning.

```scala
val numberOfLines = 4 // or much more ;-)
val numberOfColumns = 4 // or 100
spark.range(numberOfLines)
   .select((0 until numberOfColumns).map(i => rand() as s"c_$i") :_*)
   .withColumn("label", 'c_0 + 'c_1*3 - 'c_2*6 + 9 + rand())
   .show
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                c_0|                c_1|                c_2|               c_3|             label|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|0.15187732653071206|0.26585053576672046| 0.9224023831542573|  0.71091441935634| 5.360791420252281|
| 0.2808748382324112|0.14308527032596263|0.18822196601676966|0.5838190107539017| 9.077521940396766|
| 0.7039634202215999| 0.9957351040685353| 0.7726957405440454|  0.98430608640107| 8.095422483235922|
|0.38721961100842617|0.47386287403626837|  0.856405481902437|0.3888408784723435|6.1446425516061955|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

To test reading it from S3, you can write that dataframe and read it back.

Comment: Do you know of a way to use this method to generate JSON given a schema?

Comment: That's probably possible. What does this schema look like?

Comment: It's relatively complex. It is in the standard JSON schema format. Here are some examples: http://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html. My schema includes fields with regex's

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built in method that takes a JSON schema and generates data. You would have to create struct and arrays and populate yourself with `rand` or other similar functions. If you have difficulties doing it, don't hesitate to post more details.